# ReleaseByteArrayElements takes more time

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, usb

I have a JNI code to read data from USB. In the code `ReleaseByteArrayElements` takes more time.

```
jint read_linux(JNIEnv *env,jobject obj, jbyteArray j_byte_read, jint len)
{
    jbyte *c_read_ptr = NULL;
    jint read_ret = -1;
    c_read_ptr = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, j_byte_read, NULL);
    read_ret = read(file_d, c_read_ptr, len);
    if(read_ret >= 0)
    {
        // Timer1
        (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, j_byte_read, c_read_ptr, 0 );
        // Timer2
        // (Timer2 - Timer1) > 60 milliseconds
    }
}
```

Sometimes the difference between `Timer2` and `Timer1` is greater than 60 milliseconds. I tried with `SetByteArrayRegion` too. Getting the same issue.

Comment: What are your performance constraints? Are other threads accessing the `byte[]`? Is your process under a lot of garbage collection pressure? Does it make a difference if the `byte[]` is created in the function and then returned?

Comment: Alternatively, pass in a `java.nio.ByteBuffer`, as the JNI has [specific methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#nio_support) for accessing the memory behind it.

Comment: Sorry, out of station for the past few weeks. You are right, profiled the scenario and observed that ReleaseByteArrayElements takes time when the **Surviving Generations** hits the **Maximum Surviving Generations**.                                        I tried calling System.gc but it dosen't work. Is there any other solution for this without using java.nio.ByteBuffer.

Comment: I see two more options: The easy way out is to give the garbage collector more room to work with. Another is to try `{Get,Release}PrimitiveArrayCritical`.

Comment: Thanks, **The easy way out is to give the garbage collector more room to work with:** I can't get this point, could you please explain.

Comment: You can for example change the number of garbage collection generations to consider (shorter garbage collections, maybe), increase the heap size (fewer garbage collections overall), change to a different garbage collection strategy (shorter pauses or concurrent garbage collection). Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM155 or search for "jvm tuning garbage collection"